# Why did O’Shaughnessy write Ode?

Tags: poetry, historical-context

Are there any theories on what motivated  O’Shaughnessy to write *[Ode](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/54933/ode-)* (also called 'We are the Music Makers') ?

Basically, he was not a "world-forsaker" himself. I read that he worked as a herpetologist. So was it that he got inspired by his friends' lives, the way society (probably) looked down upon them, low earning etc. to write the poem?